# How to read non-binding attribute using java cdi's injection point

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld

If I have an `InjectPoint` class instance, how do I read the attributes of the Annotation from it. i.e: annotated with Qualifier `@MyCar(mpg="23")`

How would I get the mpg and `"23"` if I have an `injectionPoint` when `MyCar` is injected?

```
@Inject
public void injectionTest(@MyCar(mpg="23") Car _car,InjectionPoint ip)
{
...
}


@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface MyCar
{
    @Nonbinding
    String mpg() default "30";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(Annotation a : injectionPoint.getQualifiers())
{
   if(a instanseof MyCar)
   {
     MyCar myCar = (MyCar) a;
     a.mpg();
   }
}
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I only get a = class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 when I log the types of a, no MyCar instances

Comment: @user1889665 does `a instanceof MyCar` return `true` for any of them?

Comment: it did not but I added it to the factory method of MyCar and it reported it. even though the annotation is in class A I assume the proper way is to read it in the factory method and set() fields to store the parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid iterating through the annotations by using the getAnnotated method. You can also access other annotations this way, not just qualifiers.

```
MyCar myCar = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(MyCar.class);
System.out.println(myCar.mpg());
```